# method is changing my class variable char[][] but i dont know why java

Tags: java, arrays, char

I really didnt know what to call this question so feel free to edit it...

basically i have a char[][] class variable "canvasArray[][]"

it has been populated in a different method with characters that represent a letter on a canvas (meant to be like ASCII art)

i have a method that flips this image horizontally

```
void mirrorHorizontally()
{
    char[][]horizontalImage = canvasArray;


    for (int i = 0; i < height /2; i++)
    { 
       for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
       {            
           horizontalImage[height - (i+1)][j] = horizontalImage[i][j];           
           horizontalImage[i][j] = horizontalImage[height - (i+1)][j];
       }
    }

    printPicture(horizontalImage);
}
```

from what i can see im just setting the char[][] horizontal image to the values of canvasArray but it seems its not because if i print canvasArray instead its showing me the same.

i need canvas array to be unchanged because i have other methods that need to use it too

any ideas??

thanks in advance

EDIT: thanks to all who have answered im afraid the answer is kind of a combination of everything you have all said so i dont know whos to accept??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for something like:

```
void mirrorHorizontally()
{
    char[][]horizontalImage = new char[horizontalImage.length][horizontalImage[0].length]; // assumes all lines have same length


    for (int i = 0; i < height /2; i++)
    { 
       for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
       {            
           horizontalImage[height - (i+1)][j] = canvasArray[i][j];           
           horizontalImage[i][j] = canvasArray[height - (i+1)][j];
       }
    }

    printPicture(horizontalImage);
}
```

This way I'm creating a new buffer (not reffering and modifying the old one) and am using it directly to populate the new buffer

Comment: thanks for the answer this also works fine, its annoying because iv done this before too but just one of those times when you just get stuck on something and forget the simple answer

Comment: Been there, done that... :) sometimes going for a walk help for impossible problems ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your first call wipes over the old value at `[height - (i+1)][j]`. Instead, store that old value so that you can use it underneath:

```
char temp = horizontalImage[height - (i+1)][j];
horizontalImage[height - (i+1)][j] = horizontalImage[i][j];
horizontalImage[i][j] = temp;
```

Comment: thanks this did work and also solved another problem i had in which the original and horizontal flip image both displayed on print the horizontal array. anyway this didnt stop it overwriting the original array but i think rdcrng's answer solves this

Answer (score 1):

In Java arrays are objects. Therefore, when you assign `char[][]horizontalImage = canvasArray;` both `horizontalImage` and `canvasArray` point to the same array object. This mean that when you modify `horizontalImage` you also modify `canvasArray`. You need to copy the values from `canvasArray` into a new `horizontalImage`.

EDIT:
Try this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < height /2; i++)
   { 
   for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
   {            
       horizontalImage[height - (i+1)][j] = canvasImage[i][j];           
       horizontalImage[i][j] = canvasImage[height - (i+1)][j];
   }
}
```

and omit the assignment before the loop.

Comment: so just start the method with a for loop that sets all the values from one to the other?

Comment: If only you and @MrSpoon could merge your answers ... because both are actually necessary for a complete solution.

Comment: @user1110338 I would instead do it in your for loop logic - see edit.

Comment: @user1110338 Grimmy's answer is good. Same thing I was going for.